# Devo usar criar um serviço do tipo "Provider" só para verificar se o usuário esta logado?

Tags: angularjs, app.config, ngroute

Tenho uma aplicação que faz o uso do módulo `ngRoute`.

Quando a url de uma página restrita é acessada, verifico se o usuário está logado, para então permitir o acesso. Só que estava replicando essa rotina em várias partes do meu código. Aí pensei, vou encapsular isso em um serviço. Mas para minha infelicidade serviços do tipo `factory` e `service` não são acessiveis no bloco `config` do meu módulo. Então pensei em usar o `provider`.

Mas aí é que está. Esta é a única maneira de separar a minha rotina de verificação ou existe alguma forma que seja mais trivial?

Comment: Porque não usa SessionStorage ou LocalStorage?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto, o problema é que ele não são acessíveis no bloco 'config'